# Using Serenity framework does not open chrome browser

Tags: java, serenity-bdd

i tried to code with serenity bdd framework and i configure the serenity.conf at src/main/resources with the following content. I using chrome version 102 and serenity v 3.4.3

> webdriver {   driver = chrome   autodownload = true }

```
@Given("user is on home page")
    public void openPage() {
        loginSteps.open();
        log.info("User is on home page");

    }
```

My Additional serenity.conf

```
webdriver {
  driver = chrome
  autodownload = true
}

headless.mode = false

environments {
    default {
        webdriver.base.url = "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login"
    }
```

Comment: Did you comment out this line `headless.mode = true`?

Comment: webdriver {
  driver = chrome
  autodownload = true
}

headless.mode = false

environments {
    default {
        webdriver.base.url = "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login"
    }

Comment: What about the test? is this failed or passed? Could you add your code to reproduce the issue? I use the sample from https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber-starter, it works

Comment: https://github.com/nicholaswkc34/serenity-bdd

Comment: I just change `maven.compiler.source` 13 to 11 to make it work.

Comment: Does it working right now?

Comment: yes, i just cloned your repo, changed compile to java 11 for both source and target. Run `mvn clean verify`. That's it. It runned without error.

Comment: I can run it but it without any browser open.

Comment: confirm that it opened chrome on my machine.